# Strings over 15 characters get turned to ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε

Tags: c++, serialization, stdstring

I have been implementing a factory for a component based game engine recently. I am deserializing objects by reading in from a file what component they need and what to initialize them with. It works except for when I try to read in a property longer than 15 characters. At 15 characters, it reads it in perfectly, anything longer and I get "ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε" as output.

I am using `std::string` to store these lines of text.

Example:
`JunkComponent2 test "1234567890123456" test2 "123456789012345"`
With this the value of test becomes garbage, while test2 stays perfectly intact.

Any idea's what might be going on?

```
char line[1024];

while (file.getline(line, 1024))
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string word;
    int j = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; line[i] != '\0' && i < 1024; ++i)
    {

        if (line[i] == ' ' && j > 0 && line[i - 1] != '\\')
        {
            words.push_back(word);
            j = 0;
            word = "";
        }
        else
        {
            ++j;
            word += line[i];
        }
    }
    words.push_back(word);

    // std::cout << (*Parts)["JunkComponent"]->GetName() << std::endl;

    Component* c = (*Parts)[words[0]]->clone(words);
    object->AddComponent(words[0], c);
    for (std::list<Member*>::iterator it = members.begin(); it != members.end(); ++it)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
        {
            if ((*it)->GetName() == words[i])
            {
                if (words[i + 1][0] == '\"')
                {
                    std::vector<char> chars;
                    chars.push_back('\"');
                    chars.push_back('\\');
                    for (unsigned int n = 0; n < chars.size(); ++n)\
                    {
                        words[i + 1].erase(std::remove(words[i + 1].begin(), words[i + 1].end(), chars[n]), words[i + 1].end());
                    }
                    Container((*it)->GetMeta(), GET_MEMBER(data.GetData(), (*it)->GetOffset()), (*it)->GetName()).SetValue<std::string>(words[i + 1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Container((*it)->GetMeta(), GET_MEMBER(data.GetData(), (*it)->GetOffset()), (*it)->GetName()).SetValue<int>(std::stoi(words[i + i]));
                }
                ++i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`GET_MEMBER` Macro expands to:

```
#define GET_MEMBER(P, OFFSET) ((void *)(((char *)(P)) + (OFFSET)))
```

`SetValue` Function: (data is a `void*`)

```
template <typename T>
void SetValue(T data_)
{
    memcpy(data, &data_, sizeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Please post the code. It helps with the process.

Comment: Okay, it is quite a bit, but I will try and include everything neccesary

Comment: Try to include only the relevant portions of the code. Namely, the code that is directly related to the problems you are experiencing. You can also throw in stuff that you suspect might also be contributing to the problem.

Comment: Hopefully that is enough code to get an idea for what is going on. If needed I can edit and expand the GET_MEMBER macro

Comment: Is `line` null-terminated?

Comment: It shouldn't actually matter. I can add extra stuff after the one garbage-ified string and it all goes in just fine. It is something about storing a string and putting it into the matter... Just remembered another piece of relevant code, I'll post that too

Comment: `std::stoi(words[i + i])` what does it do ? Shouldn't it be "i + 1" ?

Comment: nsuke yes it should, I just goofed and that bug hadn't surfaced yet. Good eye, but the posted problem still persists

Comment: @user3211251 I'm itching to see what that macro expands out to.

Comment: Posted the definition to GET_MEMBER macro

Comment: if you're talking about the variable words, that is a vector of strings, not a string

Comment: @herohuyongtao Where are you seeing that? And it does.

Comment: Does that `GET_MEMBER` macro actually work? I'm pretty sure its undefined behavior to do what's being done in there.

Comment: It does work. It is a hackish way to gain access to private members. It takes the base classes data address and then adds the memory offset between the member variable and the original address. This code works for EVERYTHING i need it too, except strings longer than 15 characters

Comment: @user3211251 That must be some quality code... a macro to access private members. Hey, at least you use the prefix increment operator!

Comment: It actually is, aside from this bug, I have a fully automated factory for objects. This is just part of my larger metadata/reflection system that will then be put into a Game Engine at some point

Comment: @user3211251 Why not juts make it a public member if you are just gonna hack it anyways? What if the memory isn't aligned in the same way every time? Or is that guaranteed?

Comment: It is guaranteed by doing a nullcast to the class and it's member then getting the difference between them. Also the reason for doing it is that I don't want my factory to have to know what members the class has, just to look at them and fill them in. Basically if I add a new class, with whatever members I want, I do not have to change a single line of this code for it to work with it 100%

Comment: @user3211251 Sorry... but what if (for alignment reasons) a class is layed out in this manner `[int][padding][int]` so you think you are getting an int, but really you are getting padding?

Comment: It basically checks member_address - class_address, so if a class was laid out Class(mem 100): int(mem101), padding(4 bytes), int(mem 109), for the second int it would be checking 109-100, getting the offset of 9 and then when getting the member it would take the class address of 100, add 9, and get to memory address of 109

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab having just eyed your code. `GET_MEMBER` is really nasty and I think that's where your problem is. It seems to rely on `std::string` being convertible to `char*`, which it is not. Why does your code work with strings shorter than 15? Well that's more than likely because `std::string` on most popular implementations actually contains a special case for strings where it keeps an internal buffer of length 16 ( last element \0 ) to avoid dynamic memory allocation. When the string is larger than 15 this buffer is uninitialized because it isn't used. The correct way to access the string is by using `operator[]`.

Comment: With the help of a classmate I tracked down the bug. The problem was in SetValue, it was memcpy-ing the data and breaking everything. Instead I did:

data = new T(data_);